# Selecting a span without a specific attribute, then adding an onclick function hosted from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to write a userscript on Tampermonkey for a web based game. Using jQuery or JS, I would like to make a span with `id='#notification-static-woodcutting'`  a clickable link that runs a pre-written function that the host made. The function is `openTab('woodcutting')`.

Here's the catch:

I only want the link to happen when the game removes the style "display:none;".

I don't have acccess to the openTab() function, nor can I edit the HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var woodcuttingNotification = document.getElementById('notification-static-woodcutting');

while( $(woodcuttingNotification).css('display') === null )  {
    $(woodcuttingNotification).css('cursor','pointer');
    $(woodcuttingNotification).click(function() {
        $(woodcuttingNotification).attr('onClick',"openTab('woodcutting')");
    });
  }
});
```

Ideally, I am trying to produce

```
<span style id="notification-static-woodcutting" onclick="openTab('woodcutting')">
```

If the game takes away the `style="display:none;"`... the game automatically adds and takes away the style.

The cursor doesn't change, nor does anything happen when I click, which leads me to believe that my if(selector) is wrong?

Comment: Do you want to continuously keep checking for the `style` property? Like in a loop or just want to check it on page load?

Comment: The link can't happen when display:none is set as no <span> is being rendered for the user to click.

Comment: @Varun it would have to be continuous.

Comment: @iSZ Correct, I only want the link to happen when the display:none is taken off.

Comment: @Zachary M sorry if I'm not getting this, but if we can't fire the click event until the span element is rendered, doesn't that make checking for diplay none on the element before firing our click event redundant.

Comment: @iSZ From what I understood, the user is not going to click, it has to be done programmatically...

Comment: @iSZ The span element is rendered from the start. The display:none changes automatically, but the span is always there. Sometimes the display:none will be rendered at the page loading, sometimes it will be much later.

Comment: @ZacharyM. You say it has to be continuous but you haven't used any timer?

Comment: @Varun thanks for that so we are just preventing an event trigger if display is none. In that case I'm not sure why a click event is required at all!

Comment: @Varun I changed it to a while statement, but still no difference. 
Do I need to have some sort of function that performs the check in a different manner?

Comment: @iSZ the span isn't a clickable link. The function openTab('woodcutting') was written for a <td> elsewhere. I am trying to place that function onto the span when the span is displayed.

Comment: @ZacharyM. ok so the on click event won't be fired by a user, but rather triggered from a script somewhere else.

Comment: @iSZ The onClick function should be triggered when the user clicks on the span. I am simply trying to add the onclick function when that span is visible. The visibility of the span is not always displayed. So if display:none, we won't have to worry about it. But if the span is missing the display attribute (which means it's now visible), I want to make it clickable by changing the pointer and providing an onclick function.

Comment: @iSZ So the user is going to click it :P Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Varun That's cool, I'm still a bit lost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not 100% clear of the question, but here is a try,

Have kept a `flag` to check the display status of the span, and I have a kept jquery event handler where we can check the state of the flag.

```
var flag = false;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click','#notification-static-woodcutting',function(){
          if(flag == true) 
             openTab('woodcutting');
    });

    setInterval(function(){
        if($('#notification-static-woodcutting').css('display') == 'none')
            flag = false;
        else 
            flag = true;
    },100);   
});
```

Adjust the time interval as required.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Does the var flag have to stay outside of the document ready function? 
Also, missing a third '=' in the comparison

Comment: @ZacharyM. Yes please add the `===` and if you will be needing the flag in any other function to check the display status, otherwise it can be inside `$(document).ready` as well